# How to load Google fonts asynchronously with Font Face Observer

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

After having read [this article](https://helloanselm.com/2015/using-webfonts-in-2015/) about the best ways to serve web fonts, I wanted to make use of the recent javascript library [Font Face Observer](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver/) to load Google fonts asynchronously on my website.

The [documentation](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver/#how-to-use) reads that "fonts can be supplied by [...] a font service such as Google Fonts", but it doesn't show any examples on how to actually implement this. I've read the recommended articles about the Font Face Observer listed on the [official website](https://fontfaceobserver.com/), but all of them showed how to use it with self-hosted fonts.

Did anyone use the Font Face Observer to load Google fonts? Or, could you point me to some documentation that shows how to approach this?

Comment: I fail to see why it calls itself  *loader*. The browser loads the fonts. As far as I can see, all it does is tell you when they're loaded.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It has a `.load()` method. It also tells you when the font has loaded and changes classes to your body text in order to avoid FOIT. Does the Google/Typekit web font loader remain the best asynchronous way to load fonts, in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, saw the `load` method they use in the example on the front page, but the CSS on the front page will load the font *anyway*, so I have no idea what `load` is meant to do. Re the best way: I'm not qualified to give an opinion on that. But...fonts are loaded asynchronously *by default*. I haven't felt the need yet to control the process. Clearly people do, though, so there must be use cases.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right - I've never used `@font-face`, but now that I think about it as soon as you write that in your css, it should load the font automatically. Re Re the best way: even if fonts are loaded asynchronously by default, they are still render-blocking - that's why people want to control the process.

Comment: Ah, of course! That definitely explains wanting notification.

Answer (score 3):

I've used such an approach in order to achieve fonts lazy-loading.
You have to make sure your Google font is added to the stylesheet link. After that use [FontFaceObserver](https://fontfaceobserver.com/) as usual - just pass Google font name as an argument to create a new FontFaceObserver instance.
To manage my Google fonts I've used a tiny helper [google-fonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-fonts).

Code sample will look like this:

```
import googleFonts from 'google-fonts';
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';

loadGoogleFont(fontName) {
    googleFonts.add({[fontName]: true}); // or some other options if you need
    const fontObserver = new FontFaceObserver(fontName);
    return fontObserver.load()
        .catch(err => console.log(fontName, err));
}
```

Comment: This was helpful to point me to the right solution, thanks!

Comment: For using more options of fontfaceobserver, you can visit this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontfaceobserver

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple way I have used it, though I'm unsure if it's the best way. The reason such an approach may be good is that the font loading does not block render since I have the script in my JS file at the end. So basically I start loading the font as soon as my JS file starts parsing and it gets rendered as soon as it's loaded.

```
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver'
import loadCSS from './util/loadCSS'

loadCSS('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700')
const opensans = new FontFaceObserver('Open Sans')
opensans.load().then(() => document.body.classList.add('fonts--loaded'))
```